# How to add AdMob Interstitial banner to LibGDX game with several activities and classes?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, admob

I have a game on LibGDX. According to this 
http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_banner_ads1.php
instruction I created necessery methods in AndroidLauncher.java file. And in the core file, generated by AndroidLauncher.java, I have created the controller and also interface java file
( http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_banner_ads2.php ). 
The problem is that my game has several classes which extend one another and the corresponding condition, which I want to use for displaying adMob, is not that one to which method "initialize" gives "this" from AndroidLauncher.java file. But to download and to give request for adMob is possible only from AndroidLauncher.java, because another classes are in its own game view.

How to solve this?

This is the basic code from AndroidLauncher.java

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController {

private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    private static final String INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";

    AdView bannerAd;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();    

 // Create a gameView and a bannerAd AdView
            View gameView = initializeForView(new Stork2016(this), config);

            setupBanner();
            setupInterstitial();

    // Define the layout
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            layout.addView(bannerAd, params);

            setContentView(layout);

            config.useCompass = false;
            config.useAccelerometer = false;

        public void setupBanner() {
            bannerAd = new AdView(this);
            //bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //bannerAd.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000); // black
            bannerAd.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
            bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        }

       public void setupInterstitial() {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID);
            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            AdRequest ad = builder.build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(ad);

        @Override
        public void showInterstitialAd(final Runnable then) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (then != null) {
                        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdClosed() {
                                Gdx.app.postRunnable(then);
                                AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                                AdRequest ad = builder.build();
                                interstitialAd.loadAd(ad);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isWifiConnected() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo ni = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            return (ni != null && ni.isConnected());
        }        

        @Override
        public void showBannerAd() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                    AdRequest ad = builder.build();
                    bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void hideBannerAd() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

And then we have file Stork2016.java in which we create AdsController to be able to use methods for adds in AndroidLauncher.java.

```
private AdsController adsController;

public Stork2016(AdsController adsController){
        this.adsController = adsController;
    }
@Override
    public void create () {
        adsController.showBannerAd();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        gsm = new GameStateManager();
        music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music.mp3"));
        music.setLooping(true);
        music.setVolume(0.5f);
        music.play();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));    
    }
```

And also we have interface java file AdsController.java

```
public interface AdsController {    
    public void showBannerAd();
    public void hideBannerAd();
    public void showInterstitialAd (Runnable then);
    public boolean isWifiConnected();    
}
```

So, as we can see in Stork2016 we have "gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));" and in MenuState.java I have "gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));". In PlayState.java there is the part of code:

```
@Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();
        updateGround();
       ....

            if (tube.collides(bird.getBounds()))
                gsm.set(new GameOver(gsm));
               ...
            }
      }    
        camera.update();    
    }
```

The condition "if" frome the above code I want to use to show interstitial adMob. But it is impossibe, because the contoller which takes methods from AndroidLauncher.java can be created only in Stork2016.java. And also in AndroidLauncher.java there is
View gameView = initializeForView(new Stork2016(this), config);
wich transfers "this" to Stork2016, where is the controller.

Comment: I don't understand your question, please provide us some code

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my `AndroidLauncher` activity I start the game and initialize the `Insterstitial` ad. Then I initialize my [interface](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) which I call from inside the game, to trigger show/hide of the interstitial ad.

For example I have method showInterstitialAd() in my interface listener, then my implementation on Android would be:

```
@Override
public void showCoverAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And on iOS-MOE:

```
@Override
public void showCoverAd() {
    if (gadInterstitial.isReady()) {
        gadInterstitial.presentFromRootViewController(uiViewController);
    }
}
```

So you need the make sure that the interface listener knows about the interstitial ad, for example `AndroidLauncher implements MyGameEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

In my case interface  AdsController.java is implemented in AndroidLauncher.java:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController { ...
```

And then by this part of code:

```
View gameView = initializeForView(new Stork2016(this), config);
```

we send "this" to new class Strork2016.java.
And in the class Stork2016.java I create constructor:

```
private AdsController adsController;

public Stork2016(AdsController adsController){
        this.adsController = adsController;
    }
```

which lets us use methods from interface AdsController.java.

But only in this class Stork2016. If I want to use it in another class:

```
 gsm.push(new MenuState(gsm));
```

this is impossible and this is the problem.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should use for example a Singleton. I found a small example [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/blob/master/singleton/src/main/java/com/iluwatar/singleton/IvoryTower.java#L28).

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I have solved the problem.
I had to create two consturctors in both classes: the main core class which is initialyzed from AndroidLauncher and in the class GameStateManager. Because the class, where I want admob intersitital to be called, is created by method gsm.push which is described in class GameStateManager. Actually, in GameStateManager there have already been constuructor, so I hade only to add necessary code to this constructor.